# Joomla 2.5 - Modify registration form and logic

Tags: joomla, registration, user-registration

Hello I'm new to Joomla and I want to change the way an account is created (in Joomla 2.5):

1. Change the registation form (remove one or two fields)
2. Change the registration logic: I want to add more stuff in the sent email (and a pdf attachment) and also i want to call some other functions (or make extra requests), analyse the result and then return the response to the client.

What ways are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had an earlier answer for an earlier version that didn't apply, but found [this tutorial](http://library.logicsistemi.it/en/joomla/developing-joomla-25-mvc-components-2/40-joomla-25-extend-users-data-with-custom-fields) to get myself up to speed.  it lists all the files, etc. that you need to make changes to, but doesn't mention your email requirement.  To do that, you'll likely have to look at `function register($temp)` in `components\com_users\models\registration.php`

Comment: thank you. One thing I don't understand is how can I add a drop down list were it's values are selected from a specific table

Answer (score 1):

You can change the settings from the component directory of the template in the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

you can if you install [SEBLOD](http://www.seblod.com/), it's a content constructor that can modify article form, user registration form and much more.

It will help you with almost everything you need, but to call other functions or make other requests you will nedd to digg a little more into Joomla registration.php